# Extruding a vertex at a given angle

Tags: modeling, vertices, constraints

I know I can extrude a vertex and type in the length but is it possible to extrude a `single vertex` at a given angle like 11.23 degrees and have it constrained to that angle?

Example: follow specific angles

1. extrude vertex 12.4 deg at 4mm
2. now extrude at 5.4 deg at 3.2mm
3. now extrude at 88.8 deg at 22.mm

[image: pic]

Comment: Hi :). You can create a custom 11.23° orientation and use that

Comment: I looked it up and watched a video on it https://youtu.be/b2g-eG6KkCk but how does that allow me to extrude a single vertex at a specific angle?  Do I need to create dozens and dozens of custom angles for each individual angle?

Comment: You're right, it's not very convenient :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set your pivot point to Active.
2. Extrude your vertex while locked to a reference axis. Choose length now
3. Select the previous vertex such that it becomes active.
4. Rotate by desired angle.
5. Adjust length by scaling if needed.

[image: step 4, illustrated]

step 3, illustrated